# Best practice to communicate 'direct' registration with a website (not through Facebook, Twitter, Google, etc)

Tags: registration, login, facebook-connect, google+, openid

When offering registration on a website with the options to signup with Facebook, Google, etc. What is the best way to say to register 'directly' with the website and not using any external third parties services.

**i.e. for site xyz.com**

> Signup with Facebook
>
> Signup with Twitter
>
> Signup with Google
>
> Signup directly with xyz.com??

To me, using the word 'directly' sounds a little clumsy, and not great English either.

Comment: I wish that we could eliminate this option altogether. But alas, there is no 100% universally guaranteed third party login.

Answer (score 2):

A slight change in wording should do the trick here.  Since the accounts on other services already exist, rather than Sign *up* (which generally indicates creating a whole new account) say:

> Sign in with Facebook
>
> Sign in with Twitter
>
> Sign in with Google

Then for creating a new account on your site,

> Sign up with xyz.com

Comment: Sounds better, however, is only correct for users without an existing xyz.com username.

Answer (score 1):

I like the sites that present the option as two sides to a box. Sign up for an account or sign  up using Facebook, Twitter, etc. (using the social icons). I can't think of an example right now. But I think this is the best compromise for the UX

```
Sign in to XYZ.com   Or Sign in using  

Username             Facebook          
                     Twitter
                     Google
Password

Not Registered?
Sign up here
```

Answer (score 0):

I question whether you need to say "directly" at all. Why complicate it? If the main choice is to Sign-up with the native system or to Sign-up via a 3rd party system you could simply present it as:

**Sign-up**

-or-

**Sign-up via:**
Facebook | Twitter | Google

Answer (score 0):

How about

Sign in via* `xyz` `gmail` `yahoo` `facebook` `additional options...`
or
create a new account and sign in via* `xyz` `gmail` `yahoo` `facebook` `additional options...`

With an explanation for users...

** Signing up via a 3rd party site does **not** enable use to see your password there and will not allow us to send you unsolicited mail*